# iOS Swift: Filter array to unique items

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have an array that looks like this:

```
let records = [
    ["created": NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: 1422600000), "type": 0],
    ["created": NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: 1422600000), "type": 0],
    ["created": NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: 1422600000), "type": 1],
    ["created": NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: 1422600000), "type": 1],
    ["created": NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: 1422700000), "type": 2],
    ["created": NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: 1422700000), "type": 2],
]
```

How would I filter the array to only records with unique types?

Comment: Which version of Swift you are using?

Answer (score 7):

Try:

```
var seenType:[Int:Bool] = [:]
let result = records.filter {
    seenType.updateValue(false, forKey: $0["type"] as Int) ?? true
}
```

Basically this code is a shortcut of the following:

```
let result = records.filter { element in
    let type = element["type"] as Int

    // .updateValue(false, forKey:) 
    let retValue:Bool? = seenType[type]
    seenType[type] = false

    // ?? true
    if retValue != nil {
        return retValue!
    }
    else {
        return true
    }
}
```

`updateValue` of `Dictionary` returns *old value* if the key exists, or `nil` if it's a new key.

Comment: You need to explain the answer. Why does this code work etc...

Comment: nice one. Good answer.

Comment: Elegant! (Even if setting `seenType[type]` to `false` if the type *has* been seen is quite counter-intuitive :) – With Swift 1.2 one could probably use a `Set` for `seenType`.

Answer (score 1):

There has got to be a more swift way to do this but it works.

```
var unique = [Int: AnyObject]()

for record in records {
    if let type = record["type"] as? Int {
        unique[type] = record
    }
}
```

[image]