# Calling Swift closure with parameters

Tags: ios, swift

I am new to Swift and trying to write my first function that calls a closure that the user passes in.  I am having trouble calling my function (which I named fun).  I also was unable to find any examples of this online.  I just want to call my closure (I am unsure what to pass to it?) and then make a decision based on the boolean result?  This seems very easy yet I am not sure.

The goal of the method is to remove duplicates in an array based on the users specifications.  In my case I may want to pass in a certain class and an array of it and then remove all classes that have the same name property (ie a name string that matches).

```
extension Array{

    func removeDuplicates<T: Comparable>(fun: (elem: T, arr: [T]) -> Bool) -> [T]
    {
        var array = [T]()
        for element in self
        {
            if fun(elem: T(), arr: [T])
            {
                println("hello")
            }
        }

        return array
    }


}
```

Comment: Sorry, it is part of an Array extension .  So you would call this method on any array of your choosing.  I updated the code block.

Comment: I don't see yet what you are actually trying to achieve. In any case, you *cannot* write an array extension method that applies only to restricted types of elements (i.e. only to arrays of `Comparable`). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24938948/array-extension-to-remove-object-by-value or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27350941/is-it-possible-to-make-an-array-extension-in-swift-that-is-restricted-to-one-cla.

Comment: Also, this doesn't sound like it is meant to remove duplicates but instead just filter. In that case, just use the native `filter` method.

Comment: Yes, that is correct my explanation was wrong.  I really just want to return an array that does not contain duplicates of the attributes I specify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a slight generalization of [Does there exist within Swift's API an easy way to remove duplicate elements from an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25738817/does-there-exist-within-swifts-api-an-easy-way-to-remove-duplicate-elements-fro) and might be what you are
looking for:

```
extension Array {

    func withoutDuplicates<U : Hashable>(attribute : T -> U) -> [T] {
        var result : [T] = []

        var seen : Set<U> = Set()
        for elem in self {
            let value = attribute(elem)
            if !seen.contains(value) {
                result.append(elem)
                seen.insert(value)
            }
        }

        return result
    }
}
```

The `attribute` closure is applied to each array element, and
a `Set` is used to keep track of values that occurred already.
Therefore the value type `U` is required to be `Hashable` (which
is the case for strings).

Example:

```
struct Person : Printable {
    let firstName : String
    let lastName : String

    var description: String {
        return "\(firstName) \(lastName)"
    }
}

let array = [ 
    Person(firstName: "John", lastName: "Doe"),
    Person(firstName: "Joe", lastName: "Miller"),
    Person(firstName: "Jane", lastName: "Doe")
]

let result = array.withoutDuplicates( { $0.lastName } )
println(result)
// [John Doe, Joe Miller]
```

An alternative implementation is

```
func withoutDuplicates<U : Hashable>(attribute : T -> U) -> [T] {
    var seen : [U : Bool] = [:]
    return self.filter { seen.updateValue(true, forKey: attribute($0)) == nil }
}
```

which utilizes the fact that the `updateValue()` method of `Dictionary`
returns the previous value for the key, and in particular returns `nil` if the key was not set previously. This is also just a slight generalization of @rintaro's answer to [iOS Swift: Filter array to unique items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28957273/ios-swift-filter-array-to-unique-items).